# Изменение значения в условии if

Tags: ruby

Есть 2 json массива, в них есть одинаковые пары  ключ - значение. Так получилось что кодировка сбила некоторые символы в файле first.json но эти символы есть в second.json. Когда заменяю значение ключа и внутри последнего условия оно меняется. но при сохранении в файл third.json ничего не изменяется и я получаю копию файла first.json

```
require 'json'

actual_json_file = File.read('first.json')
safe_json_file = File.read('second.json')

actual_pull_id = JSON.parse(actual_json_file)
safe_pull_id = JSON.parse(safe_json_file)

actual_pull_id['Field'].each do |id|
  id['steps'].each do |steps|
    if steps.include?("?")
      puts "#{id['id']} #{steps}"
      safe_pull_id.each do |id_safe|
        if id_safe["id"] == id["id"]
          id_safe['steps'].each do |safe_steps|
            if steps.split.uniq - safe_steps.split.uniq == ["?"]
              steps = safe_steps
              puts steps
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

File.open("third","w") do |f|
  f.write(actual_pull_id.to_json)
end
```

Comment: Попробуй вместо `steps = safe_steps` написать `steps.replace safe_steps`.

Comment: @Nakilon Да сработало. Спасибо. Всвязи с чем стандартное приравнивание не сработало? Потому что когда я менял другое поле\заменил пару переменных\ тот же самый код верно отрабатывал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id['steps'].each do |steps|
```

Здесь массив `id['steps']` уже построен, поэтому в переменную `steps` каждый элемент присваивается, но в построении массива не участвует. `Array#each` итерируемый массив не изменяет, а лишь запускает как бы цикл по нему. `steps` -- это как бы ссылка, как в большинстве других языков программирования, поэтому `steps =` лишь меняет значение этой временной переменной в блоке, но не влияет на сам элемент массива, который изначально в `do end` блоке в нее присвоен.

Чтоб проходить по массивам с целью изменения его значений лучше использовать `.map`, а не `.each`, но в вашем случае проблему можно исправить использованием вместо присваивания метода `String#replace`, который мутирует строку.

```
 steps.replace safe_steps
```

В случае если б это была не строка, а массив, метод с таким же названием также сработал, но если б это был скаляр, например число (`Numeric`), то у этого класса такого метода нет, и пришлось бы код менять сильней.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо  [@Nakilon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178236/nakilon) за подсказку.

```
if steps.split.uniq - safe_steps.split.uniq == ["?"]
  steps.replace safe_steps
end
```

Comment: Давай я позже отвечу развернуто -- у меня на новом месте интернет барахлит, поэтому я не смог опубликовать ответ вчера.

Comment: Готово. Можешь принять мой ответ, если хочешь.